# Creating a CentOS 7 ISO with kickstart not working out as expected

Tags: centos, iso-image, kickstart

I wish to create an ISO file containing CentOS 7 x64 for unattended/kickstart installations.

For CentOS 6, it worked like a charm. But for CentOS 7, I am unable to create a bootable ISO image.

This is what I did:

- Mounted the original .ISO:

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/iso
  mount /work/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01.iso /tmp/iso -o loop
  ```
- Copying the files to a new directory:

  ```
  mkdir /work/kickstart 
  rsync -avz /tmp/iso/ /work/kickstart/
  ```
- Creating  a new iso:

  ```
  genisoimage -untranslated-filenames -volid 'CentOS-7.0-KS-x86_64' -J -joliet-long -rational-rock -translation-table -input-charset utf-8 -x  ./lost+found -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img  -no-emul-boot -o /work/centos7.iso -T /work/kickstart
  ```

  isohybrid -u /work/centos7.iso
- All is good so far, but when I try to boot out of this image I get:

  ```
  dracut-initqueue[577]: Warning: Could not boot.
  dracut-initqueue[577]: Warning: /dev/root does not exist
  ```

  Screenshot:

  [image]

What causes this problem?

I guess I am not creating the ISO right, it should be a simple copy of the same data.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not put that up somewhere right now.. but did that last week
> for a RHEL 7 installation but should be the same for CentOS7. Steps
> are as following:
>
> 1. get the ISO file of CentOS 7
> 2. `mount -o loop CentOS-7.0*.iso /mnt/`
> 3. `mkdir -p /CentOS-7-ISO-respin/{CentOS-7-unpacked,CentOS-7-iso}`
> 4. `rsync -avz /mnt/ /CentOS-7-ISO-respin/RHEL-7-unpacked`
> 5. put your kickstart file into `/CentOS-7-ISO-respin/RHEL-7-unpacked`
> 6. add a new line to `/CentOS-7-ISO-respin/RHEL-7-unpacked/isolinux/isolinux.cfg` (this way
>    you can use the ISO also from a DVD) label linux_ks   menu label
>    ^Install CentOS 7 with Kickstart   `kernel vmlinuz   append`
>    `initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:sdb2:/ ks=hd:sdb1:/ks.cfg`
> 7. create the ISO with: `/usr/bin/genisoimage -untranslated-filenames -volid 'CentOS-7.0-KS-x86_64' -J -joliet-long -rational-rock -translation-table -input-charset utf-8 -x ./lost+found -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot`
>    `-boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o`
>    `/CentOS-7-ISO-respin/CentOS-7-KS-iso/CentOS-7.0-KS-x86_64-DVD.iso -T`
>    `/CentOS-7-ISO-respin/CentOS-7-unpacked/ ; isohybrid -u`
>    `/CentOS-7-ISO-respin/CentOS-7-KS-iso/CentOS-7.0-KS-x86_64-DVD.iso`
> 8. `dd if=/CentOS-7-ISO-respin/CentOS-7-CSB-iso/CentOS-7.0-KS-x86_64-DVD.iso`
>    `of=/dev/XXX` (where XXX is the Device Name of your USB drive without
>    the partition number e.g. /dev/sdb) (Careful, that command destroys
>    all data on the stick.)

https://www.redhat.com/archives/kickstart-list/2014-August/msg00010.html

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing" class="soup-https-fixed). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.