# Error when making kickstart image on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, iso-image, kickstart

Prior to posting, I read this:

[Creating a Centos 7 iso with kickstart](https://superuser.com/questions/952113/creating-a-centos-7-iso-with-kickstart)

I'm trying to make a kickstart build of Linux and have a bootable ISO as a result. 
 I'm using CentOS 7.

My problem is when I try make the ISO, it errors with this:

```
genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot catalog directory '/home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux'!
```

I've copied files from the CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.iso and placed them in ~/kickstart_build.

Here's a tree of what's in ~/kickstart_build:

```
├── comps.xml
└── isolinux
    ├── boot.cat
    ├── boot.msg
    ├── grub.conf
    ├── images
    │   ├── efiboot.img
    │   ├── pxeboot
    │   │   ├── initrd.img
    │   │   ├── TRANS.TBL
    │   │   └── vmlinuz
    │   └── TRANS.TBL
    ├── initrd.img
    ├── isolinux.bin
    ├── isolinux.cfg
    ├── ks
    │   └── ks.cfg
    ├── LiveOS
    │   ├── squashfs.img
    │   └── TRANS.TBL
    ├── memtest
    ├── Packages
    │   ├── # A whole bunch of *.rpm files
    ├── postinstall
    ├── splash.png
    ├── TRANS.TBL
    ├── vesamenu.c32
    └── vmlinuz
```

This is the command I'm using to try and build the ISO:

```
mkisofs -o myks.iso -b ~/kickstart_build/isolinux/isolinux.bin -c ~/kickstart_build/isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -V 'CentOS 7 x86_64' -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T ~/kickstart_build/isolinux/
```

Here's the output from the terminal:

```
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
genisoimage 1.1.11 (Linux)
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/images
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/images/pxeboot
Excluded: /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/images/pxeboot/TRANS.TBL
Excluded: /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/images/TRANS.TBL
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/ks
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/LiveOS
Excluded: /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/LiveOS/TRANS.TBL
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/Packages
Excluded: /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/Packages/TRANS.TBL
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/Packages/repodata
Scanning /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/postinstall
Excluded: /home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux/TRANS.TBL
call to search_tree_file with an absolute path, stripping
initial path separator. Hope this was intended...
genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot catalog directory '/home/dogzilla/kickstart_build/isolinux'!
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you read https://superuser.com/questions/952113/creating-a-centos-7-iso-with-kickstart, did you notice they used genisoimage?

Comment: Did you notice that the two programs are common copies of each other?   genisoimage is part of cdrkit, while mkisofs is part of cdrtools.

Comment: How could I?  But assuming it is true, why use different arguments?  Also, you should realize that the same program may behave differently when called by another name.

Comment: Do you have something to contribute, like actual knowledge/experience of kickstart/making ISOs or are you just guessing?

Comment: I'm sure someone else will help you.

Answer (score -1):

make sure the file 'boot.cat' is 644 permission, then re-run mkisofs command